# 'libfakeroot:amd64' is missing final newline

Tags: 18.04, dpkg

I have gone through all solutions related to this in askubuntu. But none of these are working. Please, someone help me out. **It's an emergency.**

```
$ sudo apt upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done

The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsgutils2-2
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/59.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

The error shown is:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
     files list file for package 'libfakeroot:amd64' is missing final newline
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your disk is full. If not do:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libfakeroot
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That will clean the cache area, then get the package list, reinstall libfakeroot and then try the upgrade.